# XMPP chat integration in enterprise web application

Tags: php, xmpp, real-time, xmppframework

I am new to xmpp world. I have to build a webinar type web application where users can schedule chat/appointments with their contact. 
- Timezone of each contact will be important.
- As soon as the appointment date/time comes, the chat creator will be notified
- A group chat style conversation will start any user/contact who is online will get those chat massages instantly.
- if someone is offline, he/she will receive those massages as he/she comes online.

My question is, is XMPP suitable for such system?

Comment: Well, what kind of answers did you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen Projekts use **XMPP** like you mentioned. The **AMQP** Protocol is the other solution that comes to mind. Both are valid ways to overcome php's stateless runtime and bridge between systems.

Your delivery to the connected clients might be more complicated. Using XMPP enables some **native client**s to be used, if you want that. If you want to keep everything in a weblike environment you should deliver in **realtime** with a **node.js** server over **websockets** (socket.io).